# If $a^2+b^2+c^2=9$ prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{c^3+b^3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a^3+c^3}}\ge \sqrt[3]{\frac{a+b+c}{2}}. $

Tags: inequality, holder-inequality

Given positive real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $a^2+b^2+c^2=9.$ Prove that$$\color{black}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{c^3+b^3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a^3+c^3}}\ge  \sqrt[3]{\frac{a+b+c}{2}}. }$$

By $a=b=c=\sqrt{3}$ the inequality become an equality.

Thus, we need to prove that

> For all $a,b,c>0$ then $$\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{c^3+b^3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a^3+c^3}}\ge \sqrt[3]{\frac{81(a+b+c)}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}}. }$$

A big problem we have around the point $c=\dfrac{\sqrt{538}}{59}a=\dfrac{\sqrt{538}}{59}b$ because the difference between the LHS and the RHS in this point is  $0.000975...$

I think the problem is ver sharp and naive AM-GM, C-S is hard to apply.

Could you given some hint to prove it? Thank you.

Comment: How did you arrive at those numbers? Surely not intuition?

Comment: @insipidintegrator When I check the condition $a^2+b^2+c^2=3,$ I got that $a=b=59/50;c=\sqrt{538}/50\implies LHS-RHS\approx 0.000975$ and I claim it for homogenous problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts.**

By Holder inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}}\right)^3
 \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a^3 + b^3)(a + b + 2c)^4 \right)\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + b + 2c)\right)^4.
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + b + 2c)\right)^4
\ge \frac{81(a+b+c)}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a^3 + b^3)(a + b + 2c)^4. \tag{1}$$

(1) is true which is verified by *Mathematica*.

Comment: I find "verified by Mathematica" to be an inadequate proof.

Comment: @martycohen Yes, so I wrote "some thoughts" rather than "proof".